# Web Push sendNotifications method doesn't send notifications

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, web-push

I'm a beginner in PWA programming and I'm trying to send push notifications using web-push and service-worker. My service-worker is being registered in the application start and, after that, inside my frontend (react.js) I'm creating a function to subscribe to the logged user in the service-worker and send a notification for him from the backend (node.js with MongoDB). Here is my code:

```
 function handleSubscription(user) {
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready
          .then(async (serviceWorker) => {

            // verifying if the service worker is ready and getting the subscription
            let subscription =
              await serviceWorker.pushManager.getSubscription();

            // getting the public key from the server
            const publicKeyResponse = await Api.get("/api/user/publicKey");

            // overriding every time the subscription in my DB (mongoDB)
            if (subscription) {
              subscription.unsubscribe().then(async () => {
                subscription = await serviceWorker.pushManager.subscribe({
                  userVisibleOnly: true,
                  applicationServerKey: publicKeyResponse.data.publicKey,
                });
              });
            } else {
              subscription = await serviceWorker.pushManager.subscribe({
                userVisibleOnly: true,
                applicationServerKey: publicKeyResponse.data.publicKey,
              });
            }

            updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

            // Sending a notification after updating the subscription on Server
            sendNotificationMessage();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Service Worker Error", error);
          });
      });
    } else {
      console.warn("Push messaging is not supported");
    }

    function updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription) {
      console.log(subscription, "updateSubscriptionOnServer");

      // storing the subscription (JSON) in my User collection
      Api.put("/api/user/createSubscription", {
        _id: user._id,
        data: subscription,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res, "res update");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err, "err update");
        });
    }

    function sendNotificationMessage() {
      console.log("sending...");
      Api.post("/api/user/sendPush", { userId: user._id })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res, "res");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }
```

The methods from API used above can be described below:

```
Api.get("/api/user/publicKey")

exports.publicKey = (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .send({ publicKey: vapidPublicKey });
};
```

```
Api.put("/api/user/createSubscription")

exports.createSubscription = (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.body._id;
  const data = req.body.data;

  User.updateOne(
    { _id: { $in: userId } },
    {
      $set: {
        subscription: data,
      },
    }
  ).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Server unavailable" });
      return;
    }
    if (data.deletedCount === 0) {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "User not found" });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).send({ message: "User subscription updated" });
  });
};
```

```
Api.post("/api/user/sendPush")

exports.messagePush = (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.query._id ? req.query._id : req.userId;

  webpush.setVapidDetails(
    "<MY URL>",
    vapidPublicKey,
    vapidPrivateKey
  );
  User.find({
    _id: userId,
  }).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Server unavailable" });
      return;
    }

    if (!data) {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "User not found" });
      return;
    }
    
    // here I'm verifying if the user has a subscription stored and then I send the notification for him
    if (data[0].subscription) {
      webpush.sendNotification(data[0].subscription, "test message");
    }

    res.status(200).send(data[0].subscription);
  });
};
```

But, unfortunately, the message won't be sent to the user logged in. I already inserted the push in my `service-worker.js` file, as below:

```
self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
  let body
  if (event.data) {
    body = event.data.text()
  } else {
    body = 'Default body'
  }
 
  const options = {
    body: body,
    icon: "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon2.ico",
    vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
    data: {
      dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
      primaryKey: 1,
    },
  }
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification('Ultra Tech',    
    options))
})
```

I've tried different approaches to do that, but in all of them, my notifications aren't sent. Does anyone know why?

Note: My `vapidPublicKey` and `vapidPrivateKey` were generated by `webpush.generateVAPIDKeys()` and stored in local variables. Besides, I deployed my app (both frontend and backend) in a Heroku server to prevent problems with HTTPS and the service worker.

Note: The User collection has this structure:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  fullName: { type: String, required: true },
  cpf: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  subscription: { type: Object },
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
});
```